# Concept checking using ranges-v3 library

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

In this blog [post](http://ericniebler.com/2013/11/23/concept-checking-in-c11/), I saw Eric Niebler explaining his take on concept checking. It looked like a nice balance between simplicity and practicality for me so I wanted to give it a try.

To test things myself, I came up with a quick concept of vector spaces. Here is the code:

```
#include <range/v3/utility/concepts.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

struct vector_space
{
    // Valid expressions
    template<typename Field, typename Vector>
    auto requires(Field &&f, Vector &&v1, Vector &&v2) -> decltype(
        ranges::concepts::valid_expr(
            f * v1,
            v1 + v2
        ));
};

template<typename Field, typename Vector>
constexpr bool VectorSpace()
{
    return ranges::concepts::models<vector_space, Field, Vector>();
}

template<typename Field, typename Vector,
         CONCEPT_REQUIRES_(VectorSpace<Field, Vector>())>
void linear_comb(Field f1, Vector v1, Field f2, Vector v2)
{
    return (f1 * v1) + (f2 * v2);
}

template <typename T, std::size_t dim>
std::array<T, dim> operator+(std::array<T, dim> const& a1,
                             std::array<T, dim> const& a2) {
    std::array<T, dim> res;
    std::transform(a1.begin(), a1.end(), a2.begin(),
                   res.begin(),
                   [](T const& e1, T const& e2) {
                       return e1 + e2;
                   });
    return res;
}

template <typename Field, typename T, std::size_t dim>
std::array<T, dim> operator*(std::array<T, dim> const& a,
                             Field f) {
    std::array<T, dim> res;
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(),
                   res.begin(),
                   [f](T const& e) {
                       return f * e;
                   });
    return res;
}

template <typename Field, typename T, std::size_t dim>
std::array<T, dim> operator*(Field f, std::array<T, dim> const& a) {
    return a * f;
}

int main() {
    std::string s1 = "hello";
    std::string s2 = "world";

    std::array<float, 4> a1{1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f, 4.4f};
    std::array<float, 4> a2{4.4f, 3.3f, 2.2f, 1.1f};
    std::array<float, 4> a3 = (3.14f * a1) + (2.71f * a2);
    linear_comb(3.14f, a1, 2.71f, a2);
}
```

As you can see, I want to check that given `v1, v2` of `Vector` and `f` of `Field`, expressions `f * v1` and `v1 + v2` to make sense. In short, I want scalar multiplication and vector addition. Although I can correctly compute `a3` in `main`, function `linear_comb` tells me that concept `VectorSpace<Field, Vector>` is not satisfied. It correctly deduces `Field` as `float` and `Vector` as `std::array<float, 4>`. Why is it not seeing above as valid expressions then?

Comment: `template<typename Field, typename Vector> requires(Field &&f, Vector &&v1, Vector &&v2)` Care, your forward references should deduce the same for `v1`, `v2`(including cv and l/rvalue caterogy).

Comment: If I take one parameter and only check for the expression `v1 + v1`, still the same though.